# handling *no files* error in grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm writing some grunt plugins. I'm using `this.files.forEach` to iterate over source files. This seems to be the recommended solution. The code of a task looks, more or less, like this:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask(..., ..., function(){
  // init
  this.files.forEach(function (f) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

`this.files`, console-logged, looks something like this:

`[ { src: [Getter],
    dest: 'tmp/external-sources.json',
    orig: { src: [Object], dest: 'tmp/external-sources.json' } } ]`

However I fell into trouble when there are no recognized source files. As far as I can see, the `this.files.forEach` iterates over existing files, so the `[Getter]` (don't know, what that is) doesn't execute an iteration for non-existent files.

Now, this is a problem for me, since I change file paths frequently. And if I misconfigure the new path, **I don't get notified** about invalid paths. The only way to handle this is to scan the long console output which is really frustrating for big projects. **I'd like to be notified when source list is empty**

---

The question is... in fact, the **questions** are:
 * how can I force grunt to shout, when there are no source files for a given task/target?
 * can I change this behavior globally? I mean, can I tell grunt to shout for empty source-list for all tasks?
 * did I I misunderstand something? If so, please, correct me.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can see, the `this.files.forEach` iterates over existing
>   files

The `files` object contains all `src` objects defined in your Gruntfile, including non existing files/paths. So it will iterate over non existing paths as well.

> the `[Getter]` (don't know, what that is) doesn't execute an iteration for non-existent files

That's correct, the `src` method in the `files` object will only *get* an existing file.

> **I'd like to be notified when source list is empty**

You can iterate over `orig.src` for each of your `files` and error handle from there.
Note that if your `src` is `undefined` or `null`, grunt will warn you and abort, which is the behavior you're looking for. You can use the `--force` flag to continue but I highly discourage it.

Example:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    myTask: {
      dev: {
        files: [
          {src: 'existingFile.js', dest: 'newFile'},
          {src: 'nonExistingFile.js', dest: 'newFile2'}
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadTasks('my_tasks');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['myTask']);

};
```

**my_tasks/task.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerMultiTask('myTask', '', function() {
        this.files.forEach(function(f) {
            f.orig.src.forEach(function(src) {
                //do something with src
            });
        }); 
    });
};
```